# Ryanair (late 2018) 10kg checked-in baggage dimension

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, ryanair

Recently Ryanair added new 10kg checked in baggage option.
I have a bag that bigger then their 55x40x20cm cabin policy (something like 60x35x20) so it wouldn't pass as cabin bag. But dimensions for check-in bags (at least 20kg option) are 81x119x119.

Is it okay to buy 10kg checked-in baggage (my baggage will not exceed 10kg)? Or should I buy 20kg bag because of dimensions?

Comment: The policy is in operation by now but the details on the site are still not clear. https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/plan-trip/flying-with-us/baggage-policy

Answer (score 3):

The Ryanair luggage policy helps shred some light on the topic:

[image: Ryanair luggage policy]

It seems that the allowed dimensions for the 10kg check-in bag are the same as those for priority 2-bag carry-on fare, i.e 40cm x 20cm x 55cm. I am inferring this from the sentence (emphasis mine):

> Non-priority customers who wish to bring a second **larger** wheelie bag

where the phrase "larger wheelie bag" refers to the [extra bag that priority customers can bring as carry-on](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/baggage/priority-and-2-cabin-bags). Indeed, the maximum allowed carry-on size for non-priority customers is 40cm x 20cm x 25cm. However, priority customers can also bring a larger 10-kg bag with dimensions 40cm x 20cm x 55cm.

To be safe in your situation, you should probably purchase the 20kg check-in baggage allowance. You can try purchasing the 10kg check-in option and hope that the bag will not be measured, but I do not know exactly how the check-in procedure of these bags work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two great sources for Ryanair baggage policy. No, the [cabin bag policy](https://www.ryanair.com/ie/en/plan-trip/flying-with-us/baggage-policy) page is not one of them...

1. The news article on the corporate site: [New Bag Policy From November Will Cut Check Bag Fees & Reduce Boarding Delays](https://corporate.ryanair.com/news/new-bag-policy-from-november-will-cut-check-bag-fees-reduce-boarding-delays/) this article not only details the baggage policy but officially tells you how big the small bag sizer is. It is larger than the often posted  40 x 25 x 20cm: 42 x 30 x 20cm. Invaluable information!
2. The other, the ur document of all that is Ryanair, is the 
   [General terms & conditions of carriage](https://www.ryanair.com/ie/en/useful-info/help-centre/terms-and-conditions/termsandconditionsar_696869348). There is nothing "seems" in here, but very concrete information:

> If you purchased the 10kg Check-In Bag (up to 10kg with **maximum dimensions of 55cm x 40cm x 20cm**) you may carry your small bag on board the aircraft, however the 10kg Check-In Bag must be deposited at the bag-drop desk prior to entering security.

emphasis mine.